# Replace string representation of week with week number in R

Tags: r, date, converters, week-number

In my data file the week variable now is formatted like this

```
**week** 
May 05 2014 - May 11 2014 
May 12 2014 - May 18 2014 
May 19 2014 - May 25 2014
```

I want to convert this now to, if possible, two variables **week** and **year** signaling the week number and its year, like this

```
**week**   **year**
19         2014
20         2014 
21         2014
```

Or maybe one variable **week/year** giving a combination. Just something that is more workable than this. Would this be possible in any way?

Answer (score 0):

We can extract the substring with `sub`, convert to `Date` class, use `format` to convert to week and year and create a `data.frame`.

```
dt <- as.Date(sub("\\s+-.*", "", df1$week), "%b %d %Y")
data.frame(week = as.numeric(format(dt, "%W"))+1, year = format(dt, "%Y"))
#  week year
#1   19 2014
#2   20 2014
#3   21 2014
```

---

Or use `week` and `year` functions

```
library(data.table)
dt2 <- as.Date(sub(".*-\\s+", "", df1$week), "%b %d %Y")
data.frame(week = week(dt2), year = year(dt2))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(week = c("May 05 2014 - May 11 2014", "May 12 2014 - May 18 2014", 
"May 19 2014 - May 25 2014")), .Names = "week", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This what I get now though: `[1] week year <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)`

Comment: @user23  Your description is `I want to convert this now to, if possible, two variables week and year signaling the week number and its year, like this`  I am not sure I understand your concern.

Comment: @User23  You can either load `lubridate` or `data.table`.